# How to group multiple series in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using highcharts and looking for sultion something like
[this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36N7V.jpg)

I have treid below code

```js
var options = {
                chart: {
                type: 'line'
              },
              yAxis: [{}],
               xAxis: [{
                    categories: ['20 Apr', '21 Apr', '22 Apr', '23 Apr', '24 Apr', '25 Apr',
                        '26 Apr'],
                    crosshair: true
                }],
              series: [{
                 name: 'sms sent',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [200, 150, 170, 180, 190, 120, 254 ]
              }, {
                name: 'sms delivered',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [210, 240, 270, 280, 240, 210, 190]
              }, {
                name: 'click through',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [190, 210, 230, 240, 220, 254, 223]
              }, {
                name: 'leads',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [240, 274, 250, 220, 254, 263, 270]
              }, {
                name: 'orders',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [ 123, 174, 120, 110, 100, 154,145]
              }, {
                name: 'revenue generated',
                yAxis: 0,
                data: [200, 100, 400, 300,363, 254,245]
              }]
            }
            var chart = Highcharts.chart('graph',options);
```

but it is showing only one series.
But I need as shown in image above.
So how can I do that?

Comment: Hi @Gulzar Ali, Please describe more precisely what you want to achieve.

Comment: I tried your code, I see the all 6 series displayed on the graph